# Adding contact to gmail mailing list

Tags: javascript, php, email, gmail

I am creating a website for a university club. In that website I would like to have a subscribe feature where the user puts his email in an input and it is added to the club's mailing list. I would like to know if that is possible and if it is, what libraries/APIs should I use.

I am working with JavaScript and PHP.

Comment: I looked into the gmail api but I didn't find anything interesting

Comment: Contact groups, maybe?